# Windows refuses to recognize pyspark installation

Tags: windows, pyspark, pip

I installed pyspark using 'pip install pyspark' and it installed successfully. However, running 'spark --version' gives me `'spark' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
While 'pyspark --version' gives me `The system cannot find the path specified.`
Java (java 22 2024-03-19) and Python (3.11) are working fine.

I currently have PYSPARK_PYTHON set to python3, and %SPARK_HOME% set to [userdir]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark, but neither echoes properly. IE `echo %PYSPARK_PYTHON%` returns `%PYSPARK_PYTHON%` (same issue with SPARK_HOME). I have tried setting it manually through the advanced system settings and through the command line using setx /m. I see both in the system variables with the correct values. My best guess is that they somehow aren't set properly somehow (hence the bad echo) or the path isn't correct (should it be the bin directory? the cmd file?). Does anyone know the fix for this?
Im trying to do this in vscode if it matters but the issue is the same on the command prompt. I'm only trying to run spark locally so I don't need a full installation.

Comment: Have you added the pyspark location to your `PATH` variable? Also, make sure that pyspark actually includes an executable named `spark`. When you echo an environment variable and it displays as you indicate in your question, it means the variable is not set in your command session. You can check which variables are actually present bye typing `set p` to list all variable starting with that letter.

Comment: It may be that after using `setx` you need to start a new cmd shell for it to take effect.

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned I already tried starting a new shell (and restarted vs code). Pyspark doesn't have a spark exe but it does have variations of that? spark-shell.cmd, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I have never use this package so cannot offer any further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `SPARK_HOME` environment variable does not point to spark. `PySpark` is just the python library on how you can enroll all functionalities of spark or better said: `PySpark` is an interface for `Apache Spark` in `Python`.

You need to download spark from `https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html`.

Also consider downloading the corresponding winutils and set them as `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.
Download the required winutils from `https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils`.

[image]

For all `Pycharm` users: It might be helpful solving `PySpark` problems by adding the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variable. As I setup `PySpark` now a lot of times also on Visual Studio the way to setup spark in Pycharm is much smoother.

For all others that are not willing to run into installation problems on windows just use docker containers. But this is then another question on how to setup the Dockerfile and its mounting paths properly. :)

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me. I DLed Spark, which I located exactly like you did above, and changed the path to point to it just like in your photo (obv with the version changed). I change PYSPARK_PYTHON to point to the python exe like you have. I DLed the hadoop winutils and dropped the bin into the spark folder, and pointed it there (I assume there should just be a bin directory in that folder, as that's all there was in the git). I get the same error.

Comment: can u share an image on how your filesystem looks like? also an output of the java version in the cmd.

Comment: the winutils should be placed not in the spark folder. It should be placed in the hadoop/<your_hadoop_version>/bin/ folder.
Also consider https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-spark-on-windows-10

Comment: For some reason it's not letting me edit the post to add photos, but Java version is:
java 22 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22+36-2370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22+36-2370, mixed mode, sharing)
I tried writing out the file structure, but it appears you can have newlines in comments, though it sounds like the hadoop location is the anomaly. I recognize it's not the convention, I just didn't want endless folders and since it's looking for the bin I didn't think it would matter, right? I don't have a version of hadoop, do I need one? Will try that link!

Comment: When you click on the link of my post then it shows you the requirements. If you want to use spark 3.5.1 then you need to download hadoop 3.3. or later. Also consider using Java 17. At the end you shoud have folder more or less similiar called like C:/hadoop/hadoop_3.3/ and C:/spark/spark3.5.1. The subfolders are made in case you want to switch maybe on sometime between the versions so you only need to change the environment variables. In the C:/hadoop/hadoop_3.3/bin just copy the winutils content to c:/hadoop/hadoop_3.3./bin/<the content of the winutils folder from github> to it.